# How to add my language to github markup library?

Tags: ruby, github, markup

According to github/murkup's README, it's available to add comstomed markup language on Github. 
https://github.com/github/markup

Markdown is really clumsy to use for simple projects. I just want a markup language which supports "bold", 'inline code', 'code blocks', 'links'. No need to add blanks to change line, just be simple like code. I think it already enough in most cases. So here's my code in CoffeeScript.
https://gist.github.com/3712310

I haven't learn Ruby yet. So I don't kown how to debug my language before I push it to Github, since there's not a detailed guide for beginner. Could anyone help me?

By the way, does Github accepts such a language?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the [README](https://github.com/github/markup#commands):

> If your markup is in a language other than Ruby, drop a translator script in lib/github/commands which accepts input on STDIN and returns HTML on STDOUT. See rest2html for an example.

I encourage you to take another look at the other supported languages. Just because your file is in Markdown doesn't mean you have to use all of the features. Textile is a nice alternative, but so are all of the syntaxes supported by `markup`.

Think of tool and editor support in your language, and why users would want to use it. What does it bring to the table? What does it solve? It looks identical to Markdown, minus the features. You will likely need to sell your specialized markup language with one user in your pull request.

Comment: Rather then invent a new language, I feel more like to use gfm. But it's strange for Github not to support gfm in a repo.

Comment: @jiyinyiyong: You can definitely use GitHub-Flavored Markdown in a repo. I just tested by creating a `README.md` with code fences (````ruby), and it worked as expected.

Comment: Acctually, I want to declare line end directly as I can do in gfm, rather than adding two  blanks and the end of each line.

Comment: Here's a demo. Maybe looks bad for English. But in Chinese if there're too many characters in one line, it would be bad for reading. https://github.com/jiyinyiyong/scirpus/blob/gh-pages/readme.md